# How to tweak Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: software-center, themes, tweak

Is it possible to change some styles inside of the Ubuntu Software Center application?

For example, how can I change the rounded corners radius? Or how can I change the background color?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer would be divided into two parts:

1. Changing the dialog shapes (border shape - size - re-sizable ....)
2. changing the appearance (background color , some fonts, ... )

**To change the dialog shape**

go to the directory:

```
/usr/share/software-center/ui/gtk3
```

Open the *.ui apps with [GLADE](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/glade/). Edit whatever you want to do in appearance then save.

To install glade:

```
sudo apt-get install glade
```

for example here i change the message in the dialog that appears when something wrong goes in your sofwtare center

[image]

Enjoy this tricky

Now Also you can do some job when changing the css of the software center found in the path `/usr/share/software-center/ui/gtk3/css`.

Play with values in and see the difference and do what you want to.

For example:

open `/usr/share/software-center/ui/gtk3/css/softwarecenter.css`

```
@define-color light-aubergine #DED7DB;
@define-color super-light-aubergine #F4F1F3;


#featured-star {
    border-color: #F89516;  /* yellow */
    color: #FFC51D;         /* orange */
}
```

I would change the color of the star in the favorite part of software center

[image]

what I did is changing the border color and color of the featured star to black

```
@define-color light-aubergine #DED7DB;
@define-color super-light-aubergine #F4F1F3;


#featured-star {
    border-color: #000000;
    color: #000000;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please add an example as well?

Comment: I see there are some CSS files as well! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @IonicăBizău you are welcome